I am trying to use $graphLookup with restrictSearchWithMatch attribute different for every iteration to have dynamic graph search
I am trying to use $graphLookup in a way that the attribute restrictSearchWithMatch should be different for every iteration. See, in the below code I am trying to look for uncle so for 1st iteration, it should be:
`restrictSearchWithMatch: {relationship_type:{ $in: ["father", "mother"] } }`

and in 2nd iteration, it should be:
restrictSearchWithMatch:{ relationship_type: "brother" }


I imagine having a JSON file defining uncle like this:
{
"Uncle":[["Father","Brother"],["Mother","Brother"]],
...
}

ChatGPT generated the below code which doesn't work!
{
 $graphLookup: {
  from: "relationship",
  startWith: "$person",
  connectFromField: "person",
  connectToField: "kin",
  as: "family",
  maxDepth: 1,
  restrictSearchWithMatch: {
  $or: [
    { relationship_type: { $in: ["father", "mother"] } },
    { relationship_type: { $in: ["brother", "sister"] } }
   ]
  }
 }
},


Help me!!

Please also let me know if the same thing can be implemented using $Function (defining custom function)

aggregate([
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "relationship",
      startWith: "$person",
      connectFromField: "person",
      connectToField: "kin",
      as: "family",
      maxDepth: 1,
      restrictSearchWithMatch: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: { $eq: ["$relationship_type", "uncle"] },
              then: { relationship_type: { $in: ["father", "mother"] } }
            },
            {
              case: { $eq: ["$relationship_type", "grandma"] },
              then: { relationship_type: "mother" }
            }
          ],
          default: {} // Default match condition if no specific case matches
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

This approach allows you to have a single $graphLookup stage with dynamic iterations for different relationship searches, providing the flexibility you need to search for various relatives efficiently within a single aggregation pipeline stage. I think it should work, let me know if it does.

Yup, I can have multiple stages but I want 1 $graphLookup stage and it should be dynamic as the iterations for different relationships search will be different. Here its uncle it can also be grandma, cousin etc...

Updated the answer, Can you please check now?
